# Черный список доменных записей в bind9

Tags: безопасность, bind9

Стоит задача написать черный список с 20 доменными записями для программы bind9 для обеспечения требуемого уровня безопасности компании. Все что есть в интернете на эту тему это проверка одного конкретного url на его безопасность. Какие доменны можно ввести в данный список?

Пробовал найти информацию в интернете, а также Google safe browosing, но он не предоставляет открытую база данных, а только API для взаимодействия